# laravel object to array, returning zero for some fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Very simple query to Eloquent model, following is my workout in tinker.

In tinker I get following

```
    >>> $t1=Pomaster::all()->first()
     => App\Models\Pomaster {#3792
     ID: 77,
     poDate: "2021-05-02 18:41:50",
     vendorName: "OneVendor",
     poValue: 244132.0,
     poBy: "myGoodOrder",
     PONo: "PO-1",
     POStatus: 1,
     StoreID: "Johanesburg",
     Submitted: "2021-05-02 18:41:50",
     userName: "sumit.w",
     deleted: 0,
     lastupdate: null,
   }
```

when I query it get right answer for this filed

```
>>> $t1=Pomaster::all()->first()->poValue
=> 244132.0
```

but for `PONo` field I get zero!

```
>>> $t1=Pomaster::all()->first()->PONo
=> 0
```

I'm stuck with this for a while, and can't find any answer.
Please help
I'm on Laravel 8 and the model looks like this:

```
class Pomaster extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $table = 'pomaster';
    protected $primaryKey = 'PONo';

    public function poitem(){
        return $this->hasMany(Poitem::class,'PONo');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a kind of meditation, I could see the only reason would be the 'primary key'. it being text, was some how getting pushed to integer

So earlier my model was >>

```
class Pomaster extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $table = 'pomaster';
    protected $primaryKey = 'PONo';

    public function poitem(){
        return $this->hasMany(Poitem::class,'PONo');
    }
}
```

and now its

```
class Pomaster extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $table = 'pomaster';
//    protected $primaryKey = 'PONo';

    public function poitem(){
        return $this->hasMany(Poitem::class,'PONo');
    }
}
```

it worked, any logical explaination is most welcome!